# CS50 Why can't my code crack a four digit password?

Tags: c, cs50

I've encountered a problem in C that held me for the past 6 hours, and after research and studies, I decided to seek for help! Sorry, my English is not my first language and I am a beginner coder.

I am able to crack all passwords that are three digits long. However, it seems like I cannot crack passwords that are four digits long. I've tried my best to make some comprehension and figure out my mistakes in the code, but it seems I cannot do so. Please help!

Also, it would be very nice if there would be more explanations why I cannot crack a four digit long passwords instead of plain solution. Thank you in advance!

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <crypt.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{

    if (argc != 2){
        printf("Invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char* hash = argv[1];
    char code[4];
    char* alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    int length = strlen(alphabet);

    for (int a = 0; a <= length; a++)
    {
        code[0] = alphabet[a];
        printf("%s\n", code);
        if (strcmp(crypt(code, "50"), hash) == 0)
        {
            printf("%s\n", code);
            return 0;
        }

        for (int b = 0; b <= length; b++)
        {
            code[1] = alphabet[b];
            //printf("%s\n", code[1]);
            if (strcmp(crypt(code, "50"), hash) == 0)
            {
                printf("%s\n", code);
                return 0;
            }

            for (int c = 0; c <= length; c++)
            {
                code[2] = alphabet[c];
                //printf("%s\n", code[2]);
                if (strcmp(crypt(code, "50"), hash) == 0)
                {
                    printf("%s\n", code);
                    return 0;
                }

                for (int d = 0; d <= length; d++)
                {
                    code[3] = alphabet[d];
                    //printf("%s\n", code[3]);
                    if (strcmp(crypt(code, "50"), hash) == 0)
                    {
                        printf("%s\n", code);
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `char code[4];` is just too short for your code, and not null terminated

Comment: You know that array indexes start at zero (according to your loop) but then you should also know that the last valid index is the size *minus one*. That means a condition like (for example) `a <= length` will go beyond the end. Use `a < length` instead.

Comment: Hi, yes I've tried both and it seems like [4] is enough as I am no longer assigning more than 3 characters...

I've tried using a < length and it was giving me something like `bZZZB"u`

Comment: Char arrays have to be null-terminated if you want to use them as string in C. E.g `code` is declared as an array of 4 chars, all of them are assigned, but the call `printf("%s\n", code);` needs `code` to be null-terminated (`code[3] = '\0';`). A similar issue with `alphabet`, where all the loops are `for (int a = 0; a <= length; a++)` and `alphabet[length]` is indeed `'\0'`.

Comment: Does that mean I have to declare `code[3] = '\0'`? Does the `length` require \0 at the end?

Comment: Because strings in C are null-terminated, a string of X characters really needs space for X + 1 characters. And since you use `code` before you fill in all characters, you need `code[1]`, `code[2]`, `code[3]` *and* `code[4]` to contain the terminator at different points in your code.

Comment: Oh! I understood. I can't believe it was such a small issue that I couldn't understand. I got it working now. Thank you so much for your help everybody!

Comment: OT: it is poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not used.  I.E.  should remove the statement: `#include "cs50.h"`  Note:  Non standard header files, like `cs50.h` should be surrounded by double quotes, not lessThan/greaterThan symbols